# Android Studio and Gradle Living Together?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm poking around with the new Android Studio.

I have had no problem building (via an export/import) my project, but I have a question concerning how I can do things via the command line. I do not see a packaged stand-alone executable of gradle with Android Studio.

What is the correct approach to running my builds via my terminal?

Thoughts I've had are:

1. Install a separate version of Gradle, my concern is keeping this in-sync with Android Studio's version.
2. Using the gradlew (gradle wrapper) in sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew by adding it to my path. I'm just learning gradle so don't know if this is correct.

I'm trying to get a fine granularity to do things like:

```
    gradle tasks
    gradle assembleRelease
```

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project in Android Studio the files in sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper get copied into the root project directory.  What I did with existing projects is copy them over manually and use the gradlew script.

Comment: As I mentioned I did an import. Maybe that is why. I'll will give starting a new project a try and see if what you describe happens.

Comment: That worked, I am able to use gradle commands when creating a new project. However, the original question still stands...when doing an import is there a 'correct' way to use gradle from the command line?